# Ajax global variable is not getting saved (returns null)

Tags: ajax, globals

I am trying to modify a global variable `$lath` , It is a shortcode. This is where i have defined it.

```
function listing_order(){
    global $lath;
    $lath = array('email','phone');
    foreach ($lath as $item ) {
        get_template_part( '/inc/listingblock/listing', $item ); 
    }       
}

add_shortcode('sideblock', 'listing_order');
```

---

i want to modify the shortcode with ajax. For this i have created a  custom admin menu and options page.I want to change the `$lath = array('email','phone');` To `$lath = array('phone','email');`

**This the function which renders the menu page**

```
function listing_function_layout_control()
{

    ?>

     <div  class="info-block">
     <h2 id="info-block" >Listing Sidebar Order</h2>
     <div class="loader"></div>
     </div>
     <ul id="sortui" class="sortui">
        <?php do_shortcode('[sideblock]');?>
     </ul>

     <?php

}
```

Here `do_shortcode` is used . so it will be sortable list item

---

**This is my ajax code**
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

```
var SortList = $('ul#sortui');
var Animation = $('.loader');
var Text = $('h2#info-block');

SortList.sortable({

    update: function( event, ui){
        Animation.show();


        $.ajax({
            url: Ajax.ajaxurl,
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            data:{
                action: 'save_listing_order',
                order: SortList.sortable( 'toArray'),
                security : Ajax.security,
            },
            success: function( response ){

                $('div#message').remove();  
                Animation.hide();
                console.log(SortList.sortable('toArray'));
                .after('<div id="message" class="updated below-h2"><p>The listing order has been updated</p></div>');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('div#message').remove();  
                }, 1000);


            },
            error:function (error){
                $('div#message').remove();
                Animation.hide();
                Text.after('<div id="message" class="error below-h2"><p>Error</p></div>');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('div#message').remove();  
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    }

});

});
```

---

This is my ajax function . here i am trying to save the `$lathnew` as global variable

```
function ajax_layoutcontrol()
{

     if (!check_ajax_referer('special-string', 'security')) {
         return wp_send_json_error('Invalid nounce');
     }
     if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
         return wp_send_json_error('You are not allowed to do this');
     }

     global $lathnew;
     $lathnew = $_POST['order'];
    wp_send_json_success('Post Saved');
    //die();

}
add_action('wp_ajax_save_listing_order', 'ajax_layoutcontrol');
```

---

**But**
Now i am using this code in. single.php file.

> When i try to var_dump**global $lath;** var_dump($lath);
>   It shows

```
array('email','phone');
```

> When i try to make the global $lath= $lathnew;

```
global $lathnew;
var_dump('$lathnew'); // returns null
var_dump('$lath'); //returns null
```

I am not sure where i have made a mistake. pls help
Thanks

Comment: I’m not sure what’s going on here. I think you misunderstand how Ajax and global variables work. I think it would be better to back up several steps and describe what you want to build.

Comment: @Milo hello, Main intention is to make a sortable list (of custom post)in the backend and use in in single.php..when ever i change the sort list the backend it ajax triggers and save the order -  then it changes the layout in the frontend..may be my method is not correct..i tried to update the content inside the shortcode .

Comment: Variables don't persist across browser requests. Each page request be it a full page or AJAX starts from scratch. This isn't like Node or Python where the app starts once and runs in memory, every request loads WP from scratch, so once the page is sent to the browser, everything is discarded. You can't modify the global variable because it's created brand new each time. This isn't a WP thing it's a PHP thing. If you want to persist something between requests, you have to explicitly persist it yourself by storing it somewhere

Comment: @TomJNowell Thank you , i had a different idea about ajax functionality. I will try the to achieve the same without ajax.

Comment: This seems to be more of a custom options page necessity, which you can do with ie. the [settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API), or if that's too confusing, a custom fields plugin. And also, you should pass your variable to your shortcode via parameter, ie. `[sideblock sort="email,phone"]`. https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: @Michael Thanks,Yeah i think i have to go with  setting APi as custom field plugin usually don't give an option for sortable things.